# Find the combinations of a given encoded string using Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, anagram

I was asked this question during an interview and I couldn't come up with a satisfactory solution for it. Would appreciate if anybody could give some pointers.

Given a mapping like

```
  mapping = {"A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3..... "Z" => 26}

 encode("A") == "1"
 encode("BA") == "21"
 encode("ABC") == "123"
 encode("") == ""


decode("1") == ["A"] -> 1
decode("21") == ["BA", "V"] -> 2
decode("123") == ["ABC", "JC", "AX"] -> 3
decode("012") == [] -> 0
decode("") == [""] -> 1
decode("102") == ["JB"] -> 1


numDecode(X) == len(decode(X))
numDecode("1") == 1
numDecode("21") == 2
numDecode("123") == 3
numDecode("") == 1
numDecode("102") == 1
numDecode("012") == 0
```

We need a numDecode method which gives the length of unique solution array.

Updated :

Given a mapping like :

```
mapping = {"A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3..... "Z" => 26}

Suppose we are given a string as "A" the it can be encoded as : "1"

encode("A") should return "1"
encode("BA") should return "21" as if mapping is a hash then B has a value of 2, A has a value of 1.
encode("ABC") should return "123" as mapping["A" is 1, mapping["B"] is 2, and mapping["C"] is 3.
encode("") should return "" as it is not in mapping.


Now if decode("1") is called then it should return an array with one element i.e. ["A"] as key matching with 1 as value in mapping is "A".
decode("") should return an array with empty string i.e. [""].
decode("21") should return an array ["BA", "U"] as 2 is "B", 1 is "A" and "U" is 21 in mapping.
decode("012") should return an empty array as string starts with "0" which is not in mapping keys.
decode("102") should return an array as ["JB"] as "10" is J and "2" is B.
```

And finally numDecode should return the count of unique decoded strings in array. So,

```
numDecode(X) == len(decode(X))
numDecode("1") == 1
numDecode("21") == 2
numDecode("123") == 3
numDecode("") == 1
numDecode("102") == 1
numDecode("012") == 0
```

Comment: Your question, example code either are a little bit obfuscated. Try improve readability and verbosity of this.

Comment: I understand this (and up-voted because it is interesting mathematically - it is a product series with each term being from the Fibonacci series). You say you "couldn't come up with a satisfactory solution" - perhaps if you show what you tried, someone might show how to calculate the correct values quickly in Ruby. Considering encodings of "121212" and "12912912" might give you a pointer . . .

Comment: No, it is not a Fibonacci series. It is just a coincidence that examples look like that. For example, decode("102") should give ["JB", "B"] as combinations allowed as "102" can be split into "10","2". But if split it as "1", "0", "2" then it should not return anything as "0" is not in mapping. At least that it what explanation I got from the person who posed this question to me.

Comment: +1 for interesting question.  Two downvotes??  Bizarre.  As usual, no explanation or justification provided.

Comment: @user3075906: Yes there is a Fibonacci series here. If you cannot see it, then look harder. Try strings "1", "12", "121", "1212", "12121" etc :-)

Comment: If your question has been answered you should checkmark the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question, and the interview technique that goes with it is most likely to see how far the critical thinking goes. A good interviewer would probably not expect a single canonically correct answer.

If you get as far as a recursive `decode` solution that you then enumerate, then you are doing well IMO (at least I'd hire most candidates who could demonstrate clearly thinking through a piece of recursive code at interview!)

Having said that, one key hint is that the question asks for a `num_decode` function, not necessarily for implementations of `encode` and `decode`.

There is a deeper understanding and structure accessible here, that can be gained from analysing the permutations and combinations. It allows you to write a `num_decode` function that can handle long strings with millions of possible answers, without filling memory or taking hours to enumerate all possibilities.

First note that any set of *separate* ambiguous encoding multiply the number of possibilities for the whole string:

```
1920 -> 19 is ambiguous 'AI' or 'S' -> 'AIT' or 'ST'

192011 -> 11 is also ambiguous 'AA' or 'K' -> 'AITAA', 'AITK', 'STAA', 'STK'
```

Here `19` has two possible interpretations, and `11` also has two. A string with both of these separate instances of ambiguous codings has `2 * 2 == 4` valid combinations.

Each *independent* section of ambiguous coding multiplies the size of the whole set of decode values by the number of possibilities that it represents.

Next how to deal with longer ambiguous sections. What happens when you add an ambiguous digit to an ambiguous sequence:

```
11 -> 'AA' or 'K' -> 2
111 -> 'AAA', 'AK', 'KA' -> 3
1111 -> 'AAAA', 'AAK', 'AKA', 'KAA', 'KK' -> 5
11111 -> 'AAAAA', 'AAAK', 'AAKA', 'AKAA', 'AKK', 'KAAA', 'KAK', 'KKA' -> 8
```

2,3,5,8 should look familiar, it is the Fibonacci sequence, what's going on? The answer is that adding one digit to the sequence allows all the previous combinations *plus* those of the sub-sequence before that. By adding a digit `1` to the sequence `1111` you can either interpret it as `1111(1)` or `111(11)` - so you can add together the number of possibilities in `1111` and `111` to get the number of possibilities in `11111`. That is, **N(i) = N(i-1) + N(i-2)** which is how to construct the Fibonacci series.

So, if we can detect ambiguous coding sequences, and get their length, we can now calculate the number of possible decodes, *without actually doing the decode*:

```
# A caching Fibonacci sequence generator
def fib n
  @fibcache ||= []
  return @fibcache[n] if @fibcache[n]
  a = b = 1
  n.times do |i|
    a, b = b, a + b
    @fibcache[i+1] = a
  end
  @fibcache[n]
end

def num_decode encoded
  # Check that we don't have invalid sequences, raising here, but you 
  # could technically return 0 and be correct according to question
  if encoded.match(/[^0-9]/) || encoded.match(/(?<![12])0/)
    raise ArgumentError, "Not a valid encoded sequence"
  end

  # The look-ahead assertion ensures we don't match
  # a '1' or '2' that is needed by a '10' or '20'
  ambiguous = encoded.scan(/[12]*1[789]|[12]+[123456](?![0])/)

  ambiguous.inject(1) { |n,s| n * fib(s.length) }
end

# A few examples:
num_decode('')  # => 1
num_decode('1') # => 1
num_decode('12') # => 2
num_decode('120') # => 1
num_decode('12121212') # => 34
num_decode('1212121212121212121212121211212121212121') # => 165580141
```

It is relatively short strings like the last one which foil attempts to enumerate
the possibilities directly by decoding.

The regex in the `scan` took a little experimentation to get right. Adding `7`,`8` or `9` is ambiguous after a `1`, but not after a `2`. You also want to avoid counting a `1` or `2` directly before a `0` as part of an ambiguous sequence because `10` or `20` have no other interpretations. I think I made about a dozen attempts at the regex before settling on the current version (which I believe to be correct, but I did keep finding exceptions to correct values most times I tested the first versions).

Finally, as an exercise, it should be possible to use this code as the basis from which to write a decoder that directly output the Nth possible decoding (or even one that enumerated them lazily from any starting point, without requiring excessive memory or CPU time).

Comment: This gets my vote as the best answer.  Neil, if you are looking to change jobs, you might have a word with the SO.  I woke up this morning with the realization that the presence of zeros and pairs p such that p.to_i > 26 would partition the string into independent substrings, so num_decode would be the product of the num_code values for the substrings, but I had not recognized the Fibonacci connection until you mentioned it.  Excellent work!

Comment: One  more test: `num_decode('12'*50) # => 573147844013817084101`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
$mapping = Hash[(0..25).map { |i| [('A'.ord+i).chr,i+1] }]
$itoa = Hash[$mapping.to_a.map { |pair| pair.reverse.map(&:to_s) }]

def decode( str )
  return [''] if str.empty?
  return $itoa.key?(str) ? [$itoa[str]] : nil if str.length == 1
  retval = []
  0.upto(str.length-1) do |i|
    word = $itoa[str[0..i]] or next
    tails = decode(str[i+1..-1]) or next
    retval.concat tails.map { |tail| word + tail }
  end
  return retval
end
```

Some sample output:

```
p decode('1') # ["A"]
p decode('21') # ["BA", "U"]
p decode('123') # ["ABC", "AW", "LC"]
p decode('012') # []
p decode('') # [""]
p decode('102') # ["JB"]
p decode('12345') # ["ABCDE", "AWDE", "LCDE"]
```

Note differences between this output and the question. E.g. The 21st letter of the alphabet is "U", not "V". etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
@he = Hash[("A".."Z").to_a.zip((1..26).to_a.map(&:to_s))]
                 # => {"A"=>"1", "B"=>"2",...,"Z"=>"26"} 
@hd = @he.invert # => {"1"=>"A", "2"=>"B",.., "26"=>"Z"}

def decode(str, comb='', arr=[])
  return arr << s if str.empty?

  # Return if the first character of str is not a key of @hd
  return arr unless (c = @hd[str[0]])

  # Recurse with str less the first char, s with c appended and arr
  arr = decode(str[1..-1], s+c, arr)

  # If the first two chars of str are a key of @hd (with value c),
  # recurse with str less the first two chars, s with c appended and arr
  arr = decode(str[2..-1], s+c, arr) if str.size > 1 && (c = @hd[str[0..1]])

  arr
end  

def num_decode(str) decode(str).size end

decode('1')        # => ["A"]
decode('')         # => [""].
decode('21')       # => ["BA", "U"]
decode('012')      # => [""]
decode('102')      # => ["JB"]
decode('123')      # => ["ABC", "AW", "LC"]
decode('12345')    # => ["ABCDE", "AWDE", "LCDE"]
decode('120345')   # => ["ATCDE"] 
decode('12720132') # => ["ABGTACB", "ABGTMB", "LGTACB", "LGTMB"]
```

Any more?  Yes, I see a hand back there.  The gentleman with the red hat wants to see `'12121212'`:

```
decode('12121212')
  # => ["ABABABAB", "ABABABL", "ABABAUB", "ABABLAB", "ABABLL",   "ABAUBAB",
        "ABAUBL",   "ABAUUB",  "ABLABAB", "ABLABL",  "ABLAUB",   "ABLLAB",
        "ABLLL",    "AUBABAB", "AUBABL",  "AUBAUB",  "AUBLAB",   "AUBLL",
        "AUUBAB",   "AUUBL",   "AUUUB",   "LABABAB", "LABABL",   "LABAUB",
        "LABLAB",   "LABLL",   "LAUBAB",  "LAUBL",   "LAUUB",    "LLABAB",
        "LLABL",    "LLAUB",   "LLLAB",   "LLLL"]

num_decode('1')        # =>  1
num_decode('21')       # =>  2
num_decode('12121212') # => 34
num_decode('12912912') # =>  8
```

Comment: Thank you. Note num_decode("12121212") == 34 -> for an 8-long ambiguous sequence that is the Fibonacci sequence at position 8. In general for each ambiguous sequence of length N the number of combinations is Fib(N) - do a series product of all these and you have num_decode without needing to implement decode. If you don't think that is necessary, try your solution on '12' * 5000!

Comment: Thanks, Neil.  I'll put my mind to what you said about the Fibonacci sequence in the morn.  I'm not up to it right now.  I thought doing decode, rather than just num_decode, would be interesting, and it was.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a combinatorics problem, but it's also a parsing problem.

(You asked for pointers, so I'm doing this in English rather than dusting off my Ruby.)

I would do something like this:

1. If X is an empty string, return 1
2. If X is not a string composed of digits starting with a nonzero digit, return 0
3. If X contains no 1's or 2's, return 1 (there's only one possible parsing)
4. If X contains 1's or 2's, it gets a bit more complicated:

Every 1 that is not the last character in X matches both "A" and the first digit of one of the letters "J" through "S".

Every 2 that is not the last character in X and is followed by a digit less than 7 matches both "B" and the first digit of one of the letters.

Count up your 1's and 2's that meet those criteria. Let that number be Y. You have 2^Y combinations of those, so the answer should be 2^Y *but* you have to subtract 1 for every time you have a 1 and 2 next to each other.

So, if you haven't returned by Step 4 above, count up your 1's that aren't the last character in X, and the 2's that both aren't the last character in X and aren't followed by a 7,8,9, or 10. Let the sum of those counts be called Y.

Now count every instance that those 1's and 2's are neighbors; let that sum be called Z.

The number of possible parsings is (2^Y) - Z.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of giving “some pointers”, instead of writing an actually implementation for `numDecode` let me say that the most logically straightforward way to tackle this problem is with recursion. If the string passed to `numDecode` is longer than one character then look at the beginning of the string and based on what you see use one or two (or zero) recursive calls to find the correct value.

And the risk of revealing too much, `numDecode("1122")` should make recursive calls to `numDecode("122")` and `numDecode("22")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# just look for all singles and double as you go down and keep repeating this.. if you get to the end where the string would be 1 or 2 digets long you count 1
# IE
# 121
# 1 that's good 2 that's good 1 that's good if all good then count + 1 
# 12 that's good 1 that's good ... no more doubles if all good then count + 1
# 1 that's good 21 that's good  if all good then count + 1 
# test this on other cases

$str = "2022"
$strlength = $str.length
$count = 0

def decode(str)
    if str[0].to_i >= 1 and str[0].to_i <= 9
        $count += 1 if str.length == 1
        decode(str[1..-1])
    end

    if str[0..1].to_i >= 10 and str[0..1].to_i <= 26
        $count += 1 if str.length == 2
        p str.length
        decode(str[2..-1])
    end
end



decode($str)

p " count is #{$count}"
```